# How to access an existing sails app with a secondary domain?

Tags: sails.js

I am not familiar with sails.js, nor am I a programmer, but I have been a task assigned to allow a secondary domain to access an existing sails app. 
I currently see https://portal.firstdomain.com being served with the corresponding ssl key files setup in config/local.js. 
My task would be to allow accessing the same application with https://portal.seconddomain.com. I already configured portal.seconddomain.com to point to the same IP address as portal.firstdomain.com. I am getting a page with a configuration error message. So I guess I am reaching sails.js. There is no other webserver active on this IP address. What is puzzling to me is that firstdomain.com is not mentioned anywhere in any configuration file. Except perhaps indirectly in the ssl files which are imported in config/local.js...

Where would I find the right documentation or hints which would explain to me what to do? Any hint is very appreciated.

Dan

Comment: So your trying to have two domains land on the same website? What cloud service provider are you using?

Comment: Correct. Two domains should land on the same website.

Comment: There is no cloud service provider. sails is hosted on an own Linux server. The sails application was installed by the vendor of an accounting software as a portal to upload invoice documents. 
I am managing the linux environment, but I have no background on sails or node.js. I have found nothing in the node.js/sails folders that indicates a functionality like vhosts in an apache web server.

Comment: Use NGINX to sit in front of sails. Configure multiple server blocks. Something like this [guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-you-can-host-multiple-domain-names-and-projects-in-one-vps-7aed4f56e7a1) will help. I've a similar setup on an work intranet.

Comment: can you add screenshot of error  and details on how your server is configured to primary domain?